# Sql: obtener un ranking de datos

Tags: sql

los datos de las  estaciones metereologica se guardan en una tabla con los siguientes campos:  estacion, fecha, hora , temperatura...

Necesito obtener el ranking de las 3 estaciones con mas temperatura mas altas  actualmente,  teniendo en cuenta que la ultima lectura sea del dia de la fecha y con el ultimo dato obtenido
probe con esta pero no funciona

```
SELECT estacion, fecha, MAX(hora) AS hora, temperatura
FROM DATOS
WHERE fecha = CURDATE()
GROUP BY estacion, fecha
ORDER BY temperatura DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Que significa no funciona? Que es lo que obtienes, cual es el esquema de la tabla? Agrega mas información para que te puedan ayudar mas fácilmente sin teneer que adivinar

Comment: exacto no devuelve los datos correctos. 
la tabla se llama datos y sus campos son los siguientes:
estación (nombre de la estación metereologica )
fecha (fecha de los datos que arroja la estacion)
hora (hora en la que se tomaron los datos)
temperatura
Presion
velViento
dirViento

La consulta que puse , solo me arroja 3 resultados

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para este tipo de problemas, es necesario conocer algo llamado "funciones de ventana", (sql window functions) en ingles.
Este tipo de funciones te permiten definir un orden sobre los datos que se consultan en base a criterios que tu definas, para generar agrupamientos de datos.

Lo que tu buscas hacer, sería algo similar a esto:

```
SELECT estacion, fecha, hora, temperatura
FROM (
    SELECT
        estacion,
        fecha,
        hora,
        temperatura,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY estacion ORDER BY fecha DESC, hora DESC) AS ultima_temperatura_registrada
    FROM DATOS WHERE fecha = CURDATE()
) AS t
WHERE ultima_temperatura_registrada = 1
ORDER BY temperatura DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

Si quieres entender mas o fondo esto te invito que investigues sobre este tipo de funciones como te comenté anteriormente.

Saludos!

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!